# Flutter http.post() post user data

Tags: rest, http, post, flutter, dart

I am using Flutter to post to a url in our REST api. Most of the data is sent in the body and the params, which I am familiar with. However, the api attempts to get user data by calling `req.user.email`. My issue is that I do not know how to post data that is not in the body. My code is:

lang-dart

```
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: {
        "text": answer,
      },
    );
```

How can I incorporate user data? The user is already logged in through Firebase and I am storing the user in a custom model with all user data. Hope this isn't too obvious, I am pretty new to REST APIs.

Comment: `body: {"text": answer, "user": user.toJson(firebaseUser)}`. This `toJson` you have to implement in your model class. May be you have to encode it(Im not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Blasanka said, you should implement add a user object to your POST and it should have an e-mail. Maybe it should be cool to add a toJson method to your user class.

This code, added by @Blasanka, should do the trick

```
body: {
  "text": answer,
  "user": user.toJson(firebaseUser)
}
```